# Android Program add map activity

Tags: android, dictionary, android-activity, mapactivity

I have two classes, `Syros1Activity` and `MapActivity`
.
In the first activity (`Syros1Activity`) I have some buttons. The second is `Map`.
I want to connect one of these buttons and when I select it start MapActivity. Here is my code:

MapActivity:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import com.view.View;
import com.google.android.maps.MapView;

public class  MapActivity {

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.**onCreate**(savedInstanceState); --->Here i get a mistake The method onCreate(Bundle) is undefined for the type Object
     setContentView(R.layout.maplayout);
     MapView mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);
     mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
}

protected boolean isRouteDisplayed(){ return false;}
private void setBuiltInZoomControls(boolean b) {
     throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
}

private void setBuiltInZoomControls(boolean b) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
 }

private MapView findViewById(int mapview) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
return null;
}

private void setContentView(int maplayout) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}
}
```

Syros1Activity:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;


public class Syros1Activity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{
    private static final int PROGRESS = 0x1;
    private ProgressBar mProgress;
    private int mProgressStatus = 0;

    private static final String DEBUG_TAG = null;
    private static final OnClickListener OnClickListener = null;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Button btn11 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button11);
               btn11.setOnClickListener(this);


        Button btn12 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button12);
               btn12.setOnClickListener(this);

        Button btn13 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button13);
               btn13.setOnClickListener(this);

        Button btn21 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button21);
               btn21.setOnClickListener(this);

        Button btn22 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button22);
               btn22.setOnClickListener(this);

        Button btn23 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button23);
               btn23.setOnClickListener(this);

    }


    public void  getLocation (Location location  ) { 
        try { 
            LocationManager locMgr = (LocationManager)
                getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
            Location recentLoc = locMgr.
                getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
            Log.i(DEBUG_TAG, "loc: " + recentLoc.toString());

            }
    catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(DEBUG_TAG,"Location failed", e);

    }

    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v.getId() == R.id.Button11){
            Toast.makeText(this, "Loading Google Map", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
            .show();
            Intent intent =new Intent();
            intent.setClass(getApplicationContext(),MapActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);  
        }



         else if(v.getId() == R.id.Button12){
            Toast.makeText(this, "Loading Sights", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
            .show();
        }
         else if(v.getId() == R.id.Button13){
            Toast.makeText(this, "Loading Beach", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
            .show();
    }
        else if(v.getId() == R.id.Button21){
            Toast.makeText(this, "Loading Bars", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
            .show();
    }
        else if(v.getId() == R.id.Button21){
        Toast.makeText(this, "Loading Bars", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
        .show();
    }
        else if(v.getId() == R.id.Button22){
            Toast.makeText(this, "Loading Restaurant", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
            .show();
    }  
        else if(v.getId() == R.id.Button23){
           Toast.makeText(this, "Loading Developer Information", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
           .show();
    } 
    }



    public static OnClickListener getOnclicklistener() {
        return OnClickListener;
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Rename your `MapActivity` class, call it `MyMapActivity`

then define the class like this, `public class MyMapActivity extends MapActivity`

+

Make sure you use one of the Google APIs so you can use the Google Maps Library

+

Make sure you add this code in your `AndroidManifest.xml` (under application tag) file in order to use Google Maps

```
<uses-library android:required="true" android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
```

Comment: Thanks now is ok this problem.

Comment: You welcome, you can mark this as answer, to be useful for other people have the same as your problem, Good luck in coding!

Comment: Now when i select button which i have put mymapactivity to start i get Unfortunately, has stop.

Any help about this?

Comment: Open the activity like this, Intent intent = new Intent(this,MyMapActivity.class); startActivity(intent);

Comment: if you can get the stack trace / error log from LogCat, would be helpful to debug.

Comment: 04-22 23:54:09.507: W/dalvikvm(12297): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40c341f8)
04-22 23:54:09.507: E/AndroidRuntime(12297): FATAL EXCEPTION: main

Comment: 04-22 23:54:09.507: E/AndroidRuntime(12297): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.bountouris/com.bountouris.MyMapActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
04-22 23:54:09.507: E/AndroidRuntime(12297):  at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1511)

Comment: 04-22 23:54:09.507: E/AndroidRuntime(12297):  at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1387)
04-22 23:54:09.507: E/AndroidRuntime(12297):  at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3190)
04-22 23:54:09.507: E/AndroidRuntime(12297):  at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3297)

Comment: 04-22 23:54:09.507: E/AndroidRuntime(12297):  at com.bountouris.Syros1Activity.onClick(Syros1Activity.java:74)
04-22 23:54:09.507: E/AndroidRuntime(12297):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3591)
04-22 23:54:09.507: E/AndroidRuntime(12297):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14263)
04-22 23:54:09.507: E/AndroidRuntime(12297):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)

Comment: 04-22 23:54:09.507: E/AndroidRuntime(12297):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-22 23:54:09.507: E/AndroidRuntime(12297):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-22 23:54:09.507: E/AndroidRuntime(12297):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4507)
04-22 23:54:09.507: E/AndroidRuntime(12297):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)

Comment: 04-22 23:54:09.507: E/AndroidRuntime(12297):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-22 23:54:09.507: E/AndroidRuntime(12297):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:790)
04-22 23:54:09.507: E/AndroidRuntime(12297):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:557)
04-22 23:54:09.507: E/AndroidRuntime(12297):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: This 6 posts are all the Errors

Comment: Declare the map activity in your manifest, or if you already declared it, change the name of it in the manifest, if you don't know how, tell me and I will tell you.

Comment: <activity  android:name=".MapActivity"
           android:label="@string/app_name"
           android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
            <uses-library android:required="true" android:name="com.google.android.maps"/>   
            </activity>

Comment: Now i fix it thanks. When mymapactivity opens it appears only box. and does not loading map. can you help me?

Comment: You have to use debug key (from google), if you will only be debugging, if you will publish the application in the market you have to use release key (from google), inside the apiKey of MapView in your maplayout.xml file.

Comment: I have one more question. I want to add at the startup of my app a video 5 sec. How can i do this? I have to create a new activity? and a new layout?

Comment: Please post that in another question, its unrelated to this question, and mark my answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

did you used this permission in Manifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

if not mention it in your Manifest File out side the application tag